# How to avoid (linear) back tracking in a non-greedy regular expression?

Tags: regex

Consider the regular expression

```
".*?\s*$"
```

and a string which does not end with white space.

**Example**

`"    a"`. The final `\s` can never match the `a` which is why the
matcher iterates through:

```
\s\s\s\s\s        - fails
.\s\s\s\s         - fails
..\s\s\s          - fails
...\s\s           - fails
....\s            - fails
.....             - succeeds
```

If, however, the regex would match leading white space (`"^\s*.*?"`) the match would succeed without any backtracking. (And if the original regex would have been matched backwards (i.e. starting with the last character and working backwards), it would also succeed immediately.)

*Is there some way to hint/help the engine in the trailing case? Or is it just
the way it is?*

(I am interested in the linear backtracking at the end. I choose the white space example to illustrate my point. I would use a `trim()` function or similarly if I were to remove leading/trailing white space.)

Comment: A lazy quantifier takes one step on each iteration and immediately at this point engine continues with the next sub-pattern `\s*`.  It matches but we don't reach end of string `$` afterwards. You should see then engine backtracks on `\s*` which is greedy. *It doesn't have anything to do with previous lazy quantifier match* hence this question title does not make sense.

Comment: OP didn't say it doesn't match. @vks

Comment: @revo it does match

Comment: I said OP **is not** saying *regex does not match*, he asks about backtracking if you re-read title. @vks

Comment: @revo I don't understand. If you do have a better title, please just edit the title. I hope that the content of the question is clear and does make sense however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing something like `.*?\s*$` where `.*?` must check if there's a white-space or not before taking each character, you can use character classes and a group (atomic if possible) to limit the impact of the non-greedy quantifier.

In short, you can change `.*?\s*$` to something like `(?>\s*\S+)*?\s*$` *(obviously `(?>\s*\S+)*\s*$` or `(?:\s*\S+)*+\s*$` is faster and produces the same result)*.
When you write it this way, `\s*$` is only tested after the last non-whitespace position *(at the next white-space or at the end of the string)*.

If the atomic group feature isn't available, you can emulate it like this:

```
(?>expression)   =>    (?=(expression))\1
```

Note: for your particular case, you can also change `.*?\s*$` to `(?:.*\S)?\s*$`

Answer (score 4):

### How it backtracks

Your demonstration of engine backtracks is very brief, consisting some steps of different levels of backtracking only. Saying that, I'm going through a more explanatory way:

First level of backtracking (4 times): `()\s*`

```
\s\s\s\s$         - fails (backtrack)
\s\s\s$          - fails (backtrack)
\s\s$           - fails (backtrack)
\s$            - fails (backtrack)
$             - fails
```

Second level of backtracking (3 times): `(.)\s*`

```
.\s\s\s$        - fails (backtrack)
.\s\s$         - fails (backtrack)
.\s$          - fails (backtrack)
.$           - fails
```

Third level of backtracking (2 times): `(..)\s*`

Forth level of backtracking (1 time): `(...)\s*`

Fifth level of backtracking (zero-time backtracks of `\s*`): `(....)\s*`

```
....$        - fails (backtrack)
.....$        - succeeds
```

Total number of backtracks: **5** (number of backtracks to `.*?`) **+ 10**

### Make it less

Most number of backtracks are caused by number of white-spaces within input string and its corresponding pattern `\s*` (which is greedy): 10 backtracks.

You can lessen this number of backtracks using atomic groups (if engine supports it) this way:

```
.*?(?>\s*)$
```

It matches all white-spaces greedily and never falls into backtracking. So number of steps will be reduced like so:

Engine moves (5 backtracks):

```
\s\s\s\s$        - fails (backtrack)
.\s\s\s$        - fails (backtrack)
..\s\s$        - fails (backtrack)
...\s$        - fails (backtrack)
....$        - fails (backtrack)
.....$        - succeeds
```

*Note: I didn't include single backtracks on `\s*` at above demonstration.*

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation! What tool have you used to generate the image?

Answer (score 2):

Possessive quantifiers could help (not available in all flavors though):

```
.*?\s*+$
      ^
```

From http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html:

> Like a greedy quantifier, a possessive quantifier repeats the token as
>   many times as possible. Unlike a greedy quantifier, it does *not* give
>   up matches as the engine backtracks. With a possessive quantifier, the
>   deal is all or nothing.

Please note also that *technically, possessive quantifiers are a notational convenience to place an atomic group around a single quantifier*, which means that it's just another way to write [the solution proposed by @revo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39077984/1225328).